# Clipping an ImageSnapshot in Flex

Tags: flex4, arrays, bitmapdata

I'm using the ImageSnapshot.captureImage() method to screen capture a map image which is 2305 pixels high and 1134 pixels wide. I'm then trying to clip that image to one which is 1100 pixels high and 775 pixels wide.

```
            public function grabScreenMapImage2():void {
            // use ppi of 100 for testing
            var ppi = 100;
            var mapHeightInPixels = 1100
            var mapWidthInPixels = 775

            var snapImage:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(myMap, ppi, new JPEGEncoder());

            var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mapWidthInPixels, mapHeightInPixels);    

            var pixels:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            pixels = snapImage.data;
            pixels.position = 0; 

            var clipRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,mapWidthInPixels, mapHeightInPixels);

            bitmapData.setPixels(clipRect, pixels);

        }
```

However, I'm getting an error #2030 - end of file was encountered on my call to setPixels(), and cannot for the life of me work out why.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

DrBacchus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.  I zoom in on the original bitmap, then crop it into a new image the same size as the old one.

```
var myScaleFactor:Number = 1/3;
var zoomArea:Rectangle = bitmapData.rect;
zoomArea.inflate(zoomArea.width * imageScale, zoomArea.height * myScaleFactor);
var croppedImage = new BitmapData(zoomArea.width ,zoomArea.height,false,0xCCCCCC);
croppedImage.copyPixels(imageData,zoomArea,new Point(0,0));
var newImage = new BitmapAsset(croppedImage);
```

Comment: Very useful response. Thank you.